# How to subtract a data from a analytic formula?

Tags: data

I have the following analytic formula

```
i2k[i_] = 1/2 (i - 1) 
pixx = k^2 Exp[-2 k^2 Sin[(t)/2]^2 ](-Sin[2t] - Sin[t](1-k^2 Sin[t]^2));
piyy = k^2 Exp[ -2 k^2 Sin[(t)/2 ]^2 ](-4Sin[t]Sin[(t)/2]^2 - Sin[t](1-4k^2 Sin[(t)/2]^4)) ;
pixy = k^2 Exp[-2k^2 Sin[(t)/2 ]^2 ](2Cos[t]Sin[(t)/2]^2 + Sin[t]^2 - 2 k^2 Sin[(t)/2]^2 Sin[t]^2);

xxrot = Cos[t + 2.0 - \[Pi] / 2]^2 pixx + 
   Sin[t + 2.0 - \[Pi] / 2]^2 piyy - 
   Sin[2 (t + 2.0 - \[Pi] / 2)] pixy;
```

My simulation tried to produce the expected analytic result above as follows. The numerical result is `s11resp` which is a {30000,1, 512, 1} dimension list. The dimension is {t,1,k,1} so `t` is from `0` to `30000` and `k` from `0` to `512`.

```
Re@s11resp[[666 ;; 950, 1, 6, 1]
```

I do not know how to check whether the values of the code result in the shown specific range are close to the expected analytical formula. In other words, how can I produce the values of the analytical formula in the same range as the code result and compare them?

Comment: It is difficult to say something  reasonable without seeing  a part of `sllresp`.